# Convert array of tuples to a map

Tags: scala

What is the best functional way to convert an array of tuples:

```
Array[(String, String)]
```

to a map

```
Map[String, String]
```

Have tried the following:

```
  def arrayToMap(array:Array[(String, String)]):Map[String, String] = {
    array.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String]) ((x,y) => (x->y))
  }
```

but this compilation error is shown:

```
type mismatch; found : (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String], (String, String)) required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
```

using `toMap()` instead, as follows:

```
  def arrayToMap(array:Array[(String, String)]):Map[String, String] = {
    array.toMap()
  }
```

gives the following:

```
not enough arguments for method toMap: (implicit ev: (String, String) <:< (T, U))scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]. Unspecified value parameter ev.
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this question could be made much more useful by simply dropping almost all the code and comments, and directly asking why `Array((1 -> 2)).toMap()` results in the *"not enough arguments for method toMap"*-error. If you then quote the error exactly in the title, it's likely that you will accumulate a few upvotes over time, because it seems like it could be a not entirely obvious beginner mistake, caused by the usually omitted argument list with implicit CanBuildFrom's.

Answer (score 3):

Use toMap:

```
@ val a: Array[(String, String)] = Array(("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))
a: Array[(String, String)] = Array(("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))

@ a.toMap
res1: Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d")
```

Comment: That does not work. Have edited question to show error.

Comment: Apologies. Problem was that I was using toMap(). Removing the parameters - toMap  - appears to work

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parameters, and replacing

```
toMap()
```

with

```
toMap
```

solves the issue